# How to plot numpy arrays in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plotly

I have the DataFrame:

```
df = 

sample_type         observed_data
     A          [0.2, 0.5, 0.17, 0.1]
     A          [0.9, 0.3, 0.24, 0.5]
     A          [0.9, 0.5, 0.6, 0.39]
     B          [0.01, 0.07, 0.15, 0.26]
     B          [0.08, 0.14, 0.32, 0.58]
     B          [0.01, 0.16, 0.42, 0.41]
```

where the data type in the `observed_data` column is `np.array`. What's the easiest and most efficient way of plotting each of the numpy arrays overlayed on the same plot using `matplotlib` and/or `plotly` and showing A and B as separate colors or line types (eg. dashed, dotted, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sample_type' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
                   'observed_data' : [[0.2, 0.5, 0.17, 0.1], [0.9, 0.3, 0.24, 0.5], [0.9, 0.5, 0.6, 0.39], 
                                      [0.01, 0.07, 0.15, 0.26], [0.08, 0.14, 0.32, 0.58], [0.01, 0.16, 0.42, 0.41]]})

for ind, cell in df['observed_data'].iteritems():
    if len(cell) > 0:
        if df.loc[ind,'sample_type'] == 'A':
            plotted = plt.plot(np.linspace(0,1,len(cell)), cell, color='blue', marker = 'o', linestyle = '-.')
        else:
            plotted = plt.plot(np.linspace(0,1,len(cell)), cell, color='red', marker = '*', linestyle = ':')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: was the reasoning for using `np.linspace` just because it fully covered the range of values in `observed_data`? If new values >1 need to be plotted, how can I amend the code above to just plot the numpy arrays regardless of the range of values?

Comment: The use of linspace is just to give the plot an x-axis which is equally spaced. Note that it has len(each_array) inside. You can change it from 0-1 or 0-23 or 0-100 or anything you like.... the x-axis will show the same range. If you don't need the x-ticklabels, it can beh hidden. What do you mean by `new value > 1`?

Comment: couldn't I just do `plt.plot(cell, color='blue', marker = 'o', linestyle = '-.')` without specifying the x-axis range?

Comment: I think you can, have you tried it? Think the x-axis tick labels might change. See if that works for you. If you don't care about the x-axis, you can hide it using `plt.gca().axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)`